# Excel: Sum if the value is numeric and meet a relative criteria

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007, formula

```
     A    B        C
1    N1   4        3
2    N2   7  Blocked
3    N3   5        5
4    N4  12        0
```

I want to SUM the total of column "C" if

1. it is numeric
2. if it is less than column B

I want it to be something like this, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C1:C4<B1:B4)*IF(ISNUMBER(C1:C4),C1:C4,0)))
```

This works when there is no Text cells:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C1:C4<B1:B4)*(C1:C4))
```

This does a count instead of a sum:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C1:C4<B1:B4)*ISNUMBER(C1:C4))
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! This is actually quite simple and straightforward after reading [Excel SUMPRODUCT Function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function). Thanks to the author Dave Bruns!

The formula is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C1:C4<B1:B4),--(ISNUMBER(C1:C4)),C1:C4)
```

Comment: The Dave Burns article really is useful, particularly if you want to understand what that -- means and why -- is so useful in Excel formulae.

Answer (score -1):

In column D 1 to 4 insert:

```
=if(if(isnumber(c1),c1,0)<b1,b1,0) [repeat for each row]
```

then:

```
=sum(d1:d4)
```

is the result answer

Depending on the logic - that is to say if `c1` is a number then `c1` is to be used and if `c1` is less than `b1` use `c1` or make 0

Comment: I want to avoid adding data cells just for calculation unless I have to. Are there other ways to avoid this?

Comment: Well I looked at it and it seems there is no way around it. You either add a column that you hide OR add asheet and conduct the calcs on that sheet and return the answer to a cell on this sheet (you could also hide the second sheet)